# How to convert submitted form data into a json array and store the json array into localstorage using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

How to convert submitted form data into a `JSON` array and store the `JSON` array into `localstorage` using `jQuery` and `Javascript`? And how to print the output data on the `HTML` page?

```html
<form>
   <label>Name</label>   
   <input id = "name" type = "text"/>
   <label>Title</label>   
   <input id = "title" type = "text"/>
   
   <label>Description</label>     
   <input id = "description" type = "text" rows="4" cols="50"/> 
   
   <label>New Comments</label>  
   <input id = "comments" type = "text" rows="4" cols="50"/> 
   
   <input type="radio" name = "icon"/> like 
   <input type="radio"  name = "icon" /> unlike 
   
   <button id = "save" value = "submit">Save</button>        
   <button id = "display" value = "submit">Display</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: Haven't you tried anything? Just want us to code it for you? Please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: iApoorva:Can you make jsfiddle..Your question is not clear

Comment: Hi. If I click on the save button it should save the data into localstorage in the form of JSON array. If I click on the display button, The JSON array which is stored in localstorage should get displayed on html page.

Answer (score 0):

From [jquery .serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
   console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: The asker didn't tried anything, he didn't showed any effort or research, in SO we shouldn't answer that kind of question. Anyway, your answrd doesn't make all the 'requested code' that asker wants (json > localStorage > print html)

Comment: Hi Calvin. I have tried by the code by using JQUERY and JAVASCRIPT. This is the first time i am using the stackoverflow. I donno how to post the code properly.

Comment: Hi calvin                                                                                                          
                     var results=localStorage.getItem("json") || {info: []};
$('#save').click(function(evt) {

evt.preventDefault();

results["info"].push({
name: $('input[id="name"]').val(), 
title: $('input[id="title"]').val(), 
description: $('textarea[id="description"]').val(), 
comments: $('textarea[id="newcomments"]').val(), 
icon: $('input[name="icon"]:checked').val()
});

localStorage.setItem("json", results);

});

Comment: @ApoorvaT edit your question (there's a small button below your question, below the tags: *edit*) then add the proper code there.